# How can I retrieve address book contacts using the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework, social-networking

I want to add contact fetch (gmail,AOL,hotmail,yahoo) script in my social networking site using zend-framework.

Any one can tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imo, you would have to log in to the account, get the contact book, scrape the info, show the user the contacts and let him confirm the ones he wants to add, you may also have to have a look at the google api to achieve this.

Still, this is just how i would give it a go. :)